# Does Go's http.DefaultClient block until the last byte of the body?

Tags: http, go

For example if I had the code

```
t := time.Now()
http.Get("google.com")
fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(t))
```

Would the printed duration be after the last byte of the response's body or after the last byte of the response's headers has been received?

Comment: Doubt it waits 'cause you're supposed to be able to fetch GBs of data or hijack the connection. Try your code with a URL (full URL, not just a domain) that will take a while to download and see. Also, make it a habit to catch errors even when you don't think they'll matter; it makes me itchy just seeing the bare `err`-returning call.

Comment: It's "Get" not "GET"! Your code ignores the documentation of [`http.Get`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get) which states you need to close the returned body (unless `err != nil`).

Comment: I am very aware that the code will leak, but that shouldn't affect the timing.

I typed up this code just for the demonstration of blocking. And where I would put the timing statements. Would it make yall feel better if I checked the error and closed the response body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get) doesn't clearly state that this, but it returns as soon as the response headers have been read.

As soon as you get a little experience with Go you'll realize that almost every time you get returned an `io.Reader` (or in this case `resp.Body` is an `io.ReadCloser`) it's a streaming reader that doesn't have all the data yet.
Just like calling `os.Open` returns something that can be used as an `io.Reader` but doesn't read the whole file.

In many cases with Go, if the documentation is not clear,
you can look at the [standard package code](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go) for enlightenment.
Admittedly, in this specific case (as with `encoding/json`) the code is doing a lot so can be hard to follow at first glance.
Most of the standard packages are much easier to follow and learn from.

Failing that, you can just run a minor extension of the code you gave (on your own machine, the playground doesn't support making TCP connections) to make it pretty clear:

<sub>(note I just picked these URLs somewhat at random, better would be to pick some URL with a large payload that you know no one will mind you fetching for a test)</sub>

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func measure(url string) (t1, t2 time.Duration, n int64, err error) {
    start := time.Now()
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    t1 = time.Since(start)
    n, err = io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
    t2 = time.Since(start)
    return
}

func main() {
    for _, url := range []string{
        "http://google.com/",
        "http://en.wikipedia.org/",
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/PIA02863_-_Jupiter_surface_motion_animation.gif",
    } {
        fmt.Printf("fetching %q ", url)
        t1, t2, n, err := measure(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error:", err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("got %d bytes in %v / %v\n", n, t1, t2)
    }
}
```

E.g. on a somewhat slow connection the final URL measured above says: `597.055907ms / 29.269763851s`.
(That is, the initial `Get` call returned quickly whereas reading all the data took ~60 times longer.)

Comment: Huh I missed it in the documentation. Thanks for the info, sorry I seemed to have pissed you off.

Comment: For posterity: fetching "http://google.com/" got 20615 bytes in 228.49943ms / 246.120056ms
fetching "http://en.wikipedia.org/" got 64612 bytes in 163.696634ms / 189.106809ms
fetching "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/PIA02863_-_Jupiter_surface_motion_animation.gif" got 7876075 bytes in 90.293561ms / 1.291815772s

Comment: @PeterMichealLacey-Bordeaux, yeah, the first two URLs I thought of were too short to show a difference, the third is the full size version of an image that happens to be on the Wikipedia front page today that was big enough to clearly show a difference. It'd probably have been better if I had spent more time to come up with a better test URL that won't mind people fetching from it just to test something.

Comment: Again thank you. However the documentation that you linked does not state anything about when the function actually returns. Nor does the code that you linked to. I made an effort to track it, but eventually got [here](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go#L1031) and didn't quite understand it.

Comment: @PeterMichealLacey-Bordeaux, and to be fair, the documentation doesn't clearly state that it returns as soon as the response headers have been read, but as soon as you get a little experience with Go almost every time you get returned an `io.Reader` (or in this case an `io.ReadCloser`) it's a streaming reader that doesn't have all the data yet.

Comment: Thats a good rule of thumb. I will keep it in mind in the future. Have a good day!